# Is it okey to extract userId from JWT token

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, token

I can't quite understand how secure JWT tokens are. If a user makes an HTTP request and the JWT token is authorized. Can I fetch the UserId from the JWT (we of course store the user id in the claim). Or is there a possibility that someone can manipulate the JWT token and change his/her userId?

Incase JWT is not a good practice to extract userId. Do we have another way to do that? (.Net core web api)

Comment: Is your JWT signed?

Comment: Yes the JWT token is signed with HmacSha256Signature. I'm just thinking because when I create the token I also use a secret key.

Comment: So you can use that signature with the public key from the JWT provider to compute if the JWT has been manipulated. See the link above.

Comment: @gunr2171 When HS256 is used for the signature, there's no public key. It's a symmetric key algorithm and the token provider will keep the key secret.